# Set Managed Metadata Values via REST

Tags: javascript, rest, json

I am able to query and get an array of all my term names and guids within a Term Set, but now I want to be able to set these via REST. When I look at the structure in JSON the section with my Managed Metadata appears as follows. It seems like a sub-array

```
"TextField": "My Text",
"MMField": {
    "Label": "7",
    "TermGuid": "7d5e44d8-e5a7-4eb7-9735-7b51cea64aa8",
    "WssId": 7
},
```

Using AngularJS I have tried posting to it via the following:

```
 var itemEntry = new appItems;

        $scope.createEvent = function () {
             // Taxonomy Value Posting
            itemEntry.TextField = 'Hooray Text';
            itemEntry.MMField.Label = '7';
            itemEntry.MMField.TermGuid = '7d5e44d8-e5a7-4eb7-9735-7b51cea64aa8';
            itemEntry.MMField.WssId = '7';
            itemEntry.$save(function () {
                $location.path('/');
            });
        }
```

However, it is failing on the first option of MMField.Label as follows:

```
Unable to set property 'Label' of undefined or null reference
```

Using REST I should be able to hit the straight values and set this, but I must be missing something obvious. Any clues/what am I missing to hit the sub values within MMField?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably fails because you haven't set `itemEntry.MMField = {};`

Try using **object literal notation** (note **__metadata**):

```
itemEntry.MMField = { 
  __metadata: { type: "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" }, 
  Label: '7',
  TermGuid: "7d5e44d8-e5a7-4eb7-9735-7b51cea64aa8", 
  WssId: -1 
};
```

#### Update:

An alternative solution is to set HTTP request header `Content-Type` to **`application/json;odata=nometadata`** ([ref blog](https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) and [ref msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535600.aspx)).

Then the object literal notation would look like  this:

```
temEntry.MMField = { 
  Label: "7", 
  TermGuid: "7d5e44d8-e5a7-4eb7-9735-7b51cea64aa8", 
  WssId: -1 
};
```

Comment: It's still throwing a "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference" error. I have tried with both no metadata and verbose options

Comment: That would be a new error. In your question the error message is specifically about `Label`, which makes sense. Do you try to set a property `value` in the same manner as you were trying to set `Label`? (Perhaps pastebin/gist your code, as I suspect it differs from that in your question)

Comment: My fault. it was for another field. That is now resolved. It is clicking but giving me an 400 error/Bad Request when I try to send the Managed Metadata

Comment: Use your dev tools network-tab to look at the error message (or catch the error, or use fiddler).

Comment: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}

Comment: Did you add `{ __metadata: { type: 'SP.ListItem' }}` to `itemEntry`? You might have to send the actual type as well, you can get this from `/_api/Lists('...')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName`

Comment: Since it is a taxonomy field, I am using __metadata: { type: "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" },

Comment: Yes that is fine for the field itself, I'm talking about `itemEntry`, or whatever  you use as post body

Comment: No, I haven't needed to in the past, but that was for basic fields (text, choice, date/time). Since this is angularjs, I don't have a post body as I am using ngresource as listed in my original post

Comment: Just do this: `itemEntry.__metadata = { type: 'SP.ListItem' }`; And no you don't have to use ngresource

Comment: Since I create an item as follows:  var itemEntry = new appItems; where would I put that with my createItem function?

Comment: I just got it working! I switched back to nometadata and it did not require the field type, but required the array format as follows: itemEntry.MMField = {
                    Label: "7",
                    TermGuid: "7d5e44d8-e5a7-4eb7-9735-7b51cea64aa8",
                    WssId: -1
                }    Since you guided me to this, can you adjust your answer so I can give you credit???

Comment: So the solution was to use my snippet, but remove `__metadata`? I'm sorry but I have a hard time believing that should work, unless, are you on-premise?

Comment: I just posted the solution, but I am in SharePoint Online, and yes, your snippet made the difference. When you use the nometadata option it provides more straight access.  'save': { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() } }

Comment: Ah I see. Well I suspect my solution should work as well, as I'm using it in production, but I can update the answer with your fix as well, I think it is a neat thing to know about

Comment: I believe both with work as well. Now we have two ways to tackle it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @erikb, I needed the proper format of my code. I was using dot notation, but needed to hit the array as follows. Please note that I am using the nometadata option in my headers, so my JSON does not have the verbose aspects such as __metadata: { type: "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" }.

```
 // Create item
        var itemEntry = new appItems;

        $scope.createEvent = function () {
            console.log("Clicked");
            itemEntry.CategoryId = $scope.vm.selectedCategory.value;
            itemEntry.Title = $scope.vm.eventdescription;
            // Taxonomy Value Posting
            itemEntry.MMField = {
                Label: $scope.term.selected.termName,
                TermGuid: $scope.term.selected.termGUID,
                WssId: -1
            }
            itemEntry.$save(function () {
                $location.path('/');
            });
        }
```